# Cakephp Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, parse-error

I have a table named 'classes' in my database.

When I do a `cake bake all classes` I'm getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\timetable\src\Model\Table\ClassesTable.php on line 4
```

I understand where the error is coming from, but is there a way to get rid of this error without having to rename my 'Classes' table?

Comment: Just don't use that name

Comment: Next time you ask a question make sure you tag it with the specific CakePHP version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand where the error is coming from, but is there a way to get rid of this error without having to rename my 'Classes' table?

No you don't. :) The issue happens because CakePHP tries to bake `\App\Model\Entity\Class.php` which is [obviously](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) not going to work. The issue is **not** the *table* class name.

You will have to name the *entity* class somehow different and [tell your table object to work with that entity class](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#customizing-the-entity-class-a-table-uses). This happens because Cake expects the entity to be singular by convention and ["class" is a reserved key word in php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php). Cake inflects "Classes" to singular for the entity and thats causing the issue. So bake your model, change the entity class, then bake the controller and views.

I recommend you to read and remember [the CakePHP conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Class is a [reserved keyword of PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php), and will cause trouble if you instantiate it as such.

A solution would be to manually create a Model as thus:

```
class MyClass extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'classes';
}
```

You need to ensure that your controller $uses MyClass (inside your ClassesController).

After that, the Model should be usable as any other, despite the reserved term. Having said that, I am not 100% on the results of a bake once you've manually created the Model, so please, if you could post your results, that would be great.

Comment: He is using CakePHP 3.0 and the problem is the entity, not the Table object.